# Postgres jsonb vs composite type performance differences

Tags: postgresql, database-design, datatypes, postgresql-10, composite-types

What considerations are involved in choosing between a jsonb column and a composite type column of the same structure?

For example, consider a column like that used in the Postgres documentation:

```
CREATE TYPE inventory_item AS (
name            text,
supplier_id     integer,
price           numeric
);
```

What are the tradeoffs involved between this approach vs a jsonb column mirroring this structure?

For example, I suspect that the composite type won't require storing the key names for every record, whereas the jsonb type would require this.

Comment: IMHO don't use json for relational data.

Comment: This question is a good context to review [this other  question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62553568/287948), about "Binary to binary cast with JSONb". The "cast to composite type" performance seems a good comparison case for  [*jsonb_populate_record* function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TYPE *inventory_item* was defined in the question (same as [in the guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-DECLARING)), so we need only to define tables *tc* with composite (ROW) type, and *tj* with JSONb type.

### INSERT TIME

```sql
-- drop table tc; drop table tj;
CREATE TABLE tc (id serial, x inventory_item);
CREATE TABLE tj (id serial, x JSONb);

EXPLAIN ANALYSE 
  INSERT INTO tc(x) VALUES 
    (ROW('fuzzy dice', 42, 1.99)),
    (ROW('test pi', 3, 3.1415))
; -- Execution Time: try1 0.386 ms; try2 0.559 ms; try3 0.102 ms; ... 
EXPLAIN ANALYSE 
  INSERT INTO tj(x) VALUES 
    ('{"name":"fuzzy dice", "supplier_id":42, "price":1.99}'::jsonb),
    ('{"name":"test pi", "supplier_id":3, "price":3.1415}'::jsonb)
; -- Execution Time: try1 0.343; try2 0.355 ms; try3 0.112 ms; ...
```

Of course, we need loops, etc. something por complex to test... But seems "comparable" times, no big difference.

### SELECT NATIVE TIME

Only retrieving the original datatype. Need good benchmark, but  lets imagine something simple only to check big differences.

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYSE   SELECT x, i FROM tc, generate_series(1,999999) g(i); 
EXPLAIN ANALYSE   SELECT x, i FROM tj, generate_series(1,999999) g(i);
```

no difference again. Both with "Execution Time: ~460".

### EXPLODE TIME

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
  SELECT i, id, (x).name, (x).supplier_id, (x).price
  FROM tc, generate_series(1,999999) g(i)
; -- Execution Time: ~490 ms 
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
  SELECT i, tj.id, t.* 
  FROM tj, generate_series(1,999999) g(i),
       LATERAL jsonb_populate_record(null::inventory_item, tj.x) t  
; -- Execution Time: ~650 ms
```

Seems that is very fast to transform JSONb-object into SQL-row! Seems a *binary cast*: we can suppose that the function `jsonb_populate_record` maps the JSONb types to SQL using by `inventory_item` internal definition.

And it is **faster tham composite table**.

#### Explode and calculate something

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
  SELECT i, (x).supplier_id+i, (x).price+0.01
  FROM tc, generate_series(1,999999) g(i)
; -- Execution Time: ~800 ms

EXPLAIN ANALYSE
  SELECT i,  t.supplier_id+i, t.price+0.01
  FROM tj, generate_series(1,999999) g(i),
       LATERAL jsonb_populate_record(null::inventory_item, tj.x) t  
; -- Execution Time: ~620 ms
```

Perhaps ~150 ms to calculations, so same expected time... There are some error in the example above, need better benchmark to check real difference.

---

Check comparative time to cast from text.

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYSE -- (supposed to) cast from binary
  SELECT i, id, x->>'name' as name, 
         (x->'supplier_id')::int as supplier_id, (x->'price')::float as price
  FROM tj, generate_series(1,999999) g(i)
; -- Execution Time: ~1600 ms 

EXPLAIN ANALYSE -- cast from text
  SELECT i, id, x->>'name' as name, 
         (x->>'supplier_id')::int as supplier_id, (x->>'price')::float as price
  FROM tj, generate_series(1,999999) g(i)
; -- Execution Time: ~1600 ms
```

Long and same times. Seems that `(x->'supplier_id')::int` it is only a sugar syntax for `(x->>'supplier_id')::int`  or `(x->'supplier_id')::text::int`.

PS: this answer is also a complement for [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62553568/287948), about "Binary to binary cast with JSONb".

Answer (score 5):

It's not really a question of performance,

- Composite Types are strongly typed meaning you have to define their shape.
- JSON is weakly typed.

Moreover, JSON has a use case, but with a composite type you almost *never* want to use them because it's almost always better normalizing them into their own relations. There is an exception to that though -- when you're going to create a whole library around a set of data then composite types can make everything and nicer. For example [stdaddr](https://postgis.net/docs/stdaddr.html) in PostGIS is one such example. That type represents a physical address and multiple things can take that type (like the PostGIS geocoder).

So you can do

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( foo_id int, address postgis.stdaddr );
```

now you can get the [geocoded information relatively easily and you only have to pass around one value rather than 15](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/162043/2639).

Answer (score 3):

Using a composite type Pros

- less disc space
- faster select/insert/update

Using a composite type Cons

- it's structured (ie not flexible). You can not make up fields on the fly.
- longer coding time (especially when you use ORM)

There is one more option for storing structured data which is using another table :).
You can test yourself by creating 2 tables.